# extract query to csv is extracting as one cell

Tags: azure, csv

When extracting azure dev ops query to excel as .csv file I am seeing the data in excel but all is in one cell. For example description and title are all in one cell in the column/row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing as your description is pretty vague but I assume that the CSV column separator set on your system (probably a semicolon) does not match the column identifier used in the downloaded CSV file (most likely a comma).

To fix it:

**Windows**

- Open the Windows Start Menu and click Control Panel
- Open the Regional and Language Options dialog box
- Click the Regional Options tab
- Click Customize/Additional settings (Windows 10)
- Type a comma into the 'List separator' box (,)
- Click 'OK' twice to confirm the change
  Note: This only works if the 'Decimal symbol' is also not a comma. If you do not want to change this setting, there is another method to opening comma delimited files below.

**MacOS**

- Go to System Preferences
- Open the Language & Region pane and go to the Advanced option
- Change the 'Decimal Separator' to one of the below scenarios

Source: https://harvestmedia.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023978031-Opening-Excel-files-with-the-correct-CSV-list-separator